# Nested Route not Rendering React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom, webpack-dev-server

I am trying to nest a path within another path in `react-router-dom` version 6 and whenever I try to visit the nested argument's page (`/blog/1`), it displays a blank non-styles HTML page but when I put a child path to the root ex. `/blog` it renders perfectly fine.

Example router layout with nested argument:

```
import React from "React";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"

import Main from "./pages/Main.tsx";
import ChatGPT from "./pages/ChatGPT.tsx";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route index element={<Main />} />

                <Route path="blog">
                    <Route path=":id" element={<Blog />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};
```

Main.tsx:

```
import React from "react";

const Main = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Home page</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Main;
```

Blog.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Blog = () => {
    const params = useParams();
    const id = params.id;

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Blog ID: {id}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Blog;
```

I tried to put the `<Outlet />` tag into the root of my component's `<div>` tag that didn't work & I was expecting the react to render the nested argument's page correctly. I am also using Webpack's dev server to view the pages.

React: v18.2.0 | React Router DOM: v6.6.2 | Webpack: v5.75.0 | Webpack-cli: v5.0.1 | Webpack-dev-server: 4.11.1

Comment: I don't see any issue with the router and routes. What are `Main.default` and `ChatGPT.default`? These don't appear to be valid React components. What are you trying to render? Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] for all relevant code you are working with and trying to use?

Comment: You don't need the `Main.default`. just use `<Main>`.

Answer (score 0):

`Main` and `Blog` are default exports, which means they are default imports. Calling `Main.default` or `Blog.default` is likely returning undefined. Just Render `<Main />` and `<Blog />`.

```
import React from "React";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Main from "./pages/Main";
import Blog from "./pages/Blog";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<Main />} />
        <Route path="blog">
          <Route path=":id" element={<Blog />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: I removed the ".default" calls from all of them but that still doesn't resolve the issue. The page still shows as a blank HTML page.

Comment: @RyanV I see no overt issues in the code you've shared. Could you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you see that we could inspect live?

Comment: @RyanV FWIW I'm unable to reproduce any issue you describe in this running [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-route-not-rendering-react-router-v6-lltk7n). Feel free to fork it and see if you can reproduce the issue that we could then take a look at.

Comment: Maybe It's an issue with Webpack's dev server?

Comment: @RyanV Perhaps. Can you add your webpack config to your post?